# Purpose of converting a data into an integer first and then to a string

Tags: php, string, type-conversion, integer, codeigniter-3

I think the below code:

```
(string) intval($data[$this->config->item('rest_status_field_name')])
```

Converts the data into an integer first and then to a string. But why ?
`

The  result is always zero but the type is string.

Comment: Well, what did the original value which was input into `invtval` look like? And what type did it have? And what is this data used for after it's been converted into a string? Maybe we can tell you something, if we can actually see the context.

Comment: Could have been used to ensure the final string value actually contains just an integer - and not additional decimals, or additional gibberish. `(string) intval('1.5')` or `(string) intval('1foobar')` both result in the string value `1`.

Comment: Why not asking the person who wrote the code? With just one line of code without any context, only can be guessed.